# Error 404 in a shared hosting in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel

I have a web application that is working well in localhost but when I upload to cpanel the home page displays well but all other routes I get error 404.
So far what I have done (1) Created folder myapp in root folder
(2)Copied all public files to public_html
(3) modified the index.php two lines to

```
require __DIR__.'/../myapp/vendor/autoload.php';
$app = require_once __DIR__.'/../myapp/bootstrap/app.php';
```

In my route I have

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::class, 'index']);
Route::get('profile', [App\Http\Controllers\PagesController::class, 'profile']);
```

In my links I have

```
 <li class="nav-item active">
   <a class="nav-link" href="{{url('/')}}">HOME</a>
  </li>
   <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link" href="{{url('/profile')}}">PROFILE</a>
```

Comment: Do you have `.htaccess` file in your `public_html` directory now?

Comment: I don't see .htaccess in public_html

Comment: Can you create one with this contents: https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/.htaccess

Comment: Ok Thanks let me do it

Comment: Thanks alot Uğur Arıcı, If you are close I would buy a cup of coffee, Again thanks

Comment: You are welcome. I wrote down this as an answer in detail. If you want you can accept it to show your problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

cPanel use Apache as Web server and Apache needs to know how to handle URL rewrites which Laravel requires. To achieve this Laravel comes with a `.htaccess` file. Here is the latest version from [Laravel source code](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/8.x/public/.htaccess).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

You may not have been able to copy the `.htaccess` file from your application's `public` directory to `public_html` directory while copying the files.

To solve this you can create a `.htacess` file with specified content.